# jQuery How to get span value when clicked on other span

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get the `fileid` and filename `L98BIv2_inv_12.txt` when a user clicks on `plupload_delete` class

```
<<span id="fileId-1">
<a style="clear:left" class="item ui-corner-all" href="#" title="">
    <span id="fileId-1" class="ui-icon ui-icon-close plupload_delete"></span>
    <span class="value plupload_file_name">L98BIv2_inv_11.txt</span>
</a>
<a class="item ui-corner-all" href="#">
    <span class="value noicon plupload_file_size">1 KB</span>
</a>
<a class="item progress ui-corner-all" href="#" style="display:none">
    <span class="value noicon plupload_file_status">Uploading ...</span>
</a>
```

```
<span id="fileId-2">
<a style="clear:left" class="item ui-corner-all" href="#" title="">
    <span id="fileId-2" class="ui-icon ui-icon-close plupload_delete"></span>
    <span class="value plupload_file_name">L98BIv2_inv_12.txt</span>
</a>
<a class="item ui-corner-all" href="#">
    <span class="value noicon plupload_file_size">2 KB</span>
</a>
<a class="item progress ui-corner-all" href="#" style="display:none">
    <span class="value noicon plupload_file_status">Uploading ...</span>
</a>
```

Below is my jQuery function

```
$('.plupload_delete', target).click(function(e) {
     var fid = $(this).attr("id")
     fid = fid.replace("fileId-",""); 
});
```

I am able to get the `fileId` but I couldnt get the filename `L98BIv2_inv_12.txt` from `span` class `value plupload_file_name`

can someone help me with this?

Comment: you shouldn't have duplicate IDs for html elements, it can cause problems. Use [data-attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes) instead.

Comment: @ekuusela Sure I'll try to avoid duplicate IDs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need is `$(this).text()`:

```
 $('.plupload_delete', target).click(function(e) {
      var fid = $(this).attr("id")
      fid = fid.replace("fileId-",""); 

      var name = $(this).next().text();
 });
```

Please note that you need `.next()` because the `span` containing the file name is just after the clicked `span`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I got the `filename`  :)